# validate a JSON object using jax-rs

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

I've a requirement. lets say I have a JSON file as shown below.

```
    {
    "orgId": 27,
    "orgType":"MotorBikes",
    "orgName":"ROYAL Enfield",
    "orgAddress":"Express Estate",
    "orgCity":"Chennai",
    "orgState":"TamilNadu"
    }
```

So I need to do two validations. one is checking all the json fields and return true or false and second one should have methods to validate partial response like for example: `isExists(jsonObject, "orgType":"MotorBikes")` should return true. This comparison should be done using `jax-rs` libraries. So if anybody who is familiar with this please tell me. This would help me a lot.

Comment: JAX-RS is a standard, what's the actual json library parser you are using? Or which framework you are using to parse the json?

Comment: JAX-RS implementations cannot do this on their own. Every JAX-RS implementation has support for JSON through external libraries (Jackson is most popular). You need to find out which JSON library your setup is using and you need to use that lib's APIs.

Comment: When do you need to validate it? During a response?

Comment: Actually i'm using restassured framework for testing an existing api calls(post,put,get,delete). So i'm asserting the responses through testNG. In assertion process, for Post i will compare through status code,for GET i will compare through JSON response which is send as body through POST and for i will compare through json response. So in that comparision process i need to do the above mentioned steps as stated in my question.

Comment: `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160212</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>`

These are the two dependencies that i have @LynxZh

Answer (score 0):

Package **javax.json** should be enough.

```
import javax.json.JsonObject;

public static void main(String[] args){
    JsonObject jsonObj = /* your json */;
    boolean all = checkAll(jsonObj,new String[]{"orgId","orgType","orgName","orgAddress","orgCity","orgState"});        
    boolean one = isExists(jsonObj,"orgType","MotorBikes");
}

private boolean checkAll(JsonObject jsonObj, String[] keys) {
    for(String key: keys) {
        if(jsonObj.get(key)==null) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean isExists(JsonObject jsonObj, String key, String value) {
    return (jsonObj.get(key)!=null && jsonObj.get(key).equals(value));
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
A more focused answer using **org.json** library which is in your dependency and is a JSON library, not JAX-RS.

```
@Test
public void test() throws FileNotFoundException{        
    String jsonAsString = when().get("/your.get").then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response().asString();
    JSONObject jsonFromResponse = new JSONObject(jsonAsString);

    File file = /** Load your file ***/             
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(is);  
    while(tokener.more()) { // Iterate through Json file 
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) tokener.nextValue();
        for(String key: obj.keySet()) {     
            boolean valid = validateField(key, jsonFromResponse);
            System.out.println("'"+key+"' field "+(valid?"not ":"")+"present");
        }           
    }

    boolean v = validateValue(jsonFromResponse, "orgName", "ROYAL Enfield");    
    System.out.println("Validation: "+v);   
}

private boolean validateValue(JSONObject json, String key, String value) {
    if(validateField(key,json))
        return value.equals(json.getString(key));
    return false;
}

private boolean validateField(String key, JSONObject jsonFromResponse) {
    Object valueFromResponse = null;
    try {
        valueFromResponse = jsonFromResponse.get(key);
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        valueFromResponse = null;
    }
    return valueFromResponse!=null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Luca Montagnoli. I will let you know if it worked on not.

Comment: This should work. but, the thing is i need to use jax-rs for this purpose. please tell me if you know how to do it in jax-rs

Comment: Where exactly do you need to validate. In the server before response in @GET method), in the client after receiving the response or only in restassured assertion test?

Comment: If you are only testing with restassured you should use "body" method which provides json validation. Try like this: get("your.get.path").then().body("orgType", "MotorBikes");

Comment: i need to assert after getting response through restassured

Comment: using restassured i returned jsonobject which has some json fileds. so i need to do assert in my testng class. so my requirement is to compare these returned json fileds with the .json file contents that i have using jax-rs or any other jax-rs libraries.

Comment: I updated my answer using org.json dependency, as you need. Let's try